# Creating SSL Certs For google app engine Using ZeroSSL And Let's Encrypt

Tags: ssl, google-app-engine, lets-encrypt, zerossl

I'm trying to install ssl certificates created using the ZeroSSL.com page for Let's Encrypt, into the Google Cloud Platform.
I followed the FREE SSL Certificate Wizard to do so.
The ZeroSSL page generates four files in the process:
    domain-crt.txt
    domain-key.txt
    account-key.txt
    domain-csr.txt

The google Cloud Platform asks for two files:
    PEM encoded X.509 public key certificate
    Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key

I've made all the combinations, and followed all suggestion I could find in the web, but I had no success.

Answer (score 5):

I asked this to the zeroSSL people, and Alexander answers me with the solution.

SSL Certificate Wizard generates a longer more secure 4096 bits key by default, but Google only accepts 2048 bits key. So you should generate the new CSR separately first by using CSR Generator at https://zerossl.com/free-ssl/#csr and making sure you select 2048 bits. Then download the produced key and CSR (please note that this is the domain key, not the LE key) and then use the same LE key as you used originally and this new CSR with the SSL Certificate Wizard.
At the last Wizard step, you might need to split the domain-crt.txt file in two. The first part between ---BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and ---END CERTIFICATE----- will go into "Public key certificate" field. 
Finally, the content of domain-key.txt should be pasted into "Private key" field.

Comment: I m not clear can you please give this step by step. I got csr and after that I m not clear what you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from the command line for free:

Install Certbot client:

```
$ sudo brew install wget
$ wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
$ chmod a+x ./certbot-auto
$ ./certbot-auto --help
```

Then, to generate cert:

```
$ cd certbot (if not already there)
$ sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --debug -a manual -d www.yoursite.com -d yoursite.com (<--if you want naked too.)
```

You should get to a screen telling you the challenge url and response needed to verify domain.  Add each & deploy.  Leave each url working.  (They will be needed for renewing.)
If you do both naked and www, you will need to do the challenge urls twice, once for each subdomain.  Finally, you should get this message:

- Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yoursite.com/fullchain.pem. Your cert will
  expire on 2016-xx-07. To obtain a new or tweaked version of this
  certificate in the future, simply run certbot-auto again. To
  non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
  "certbot-auto renew"

Change directory to where pem files are placed:

```
$ cd /private/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yoursite.com
```

Create unencrypted key (this is the one you upload to GAE.  If fails, use the original privkey.pem):

```
$ sudo openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out unencrypted_key.pem
```

Go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/certificates?project=yoursite.  Click on `Upload a new SSL certificate`

Open these PEM files in a text editor, and copy/paste the contents in the fields. (`fullchain.pem` is the public key.  `unencrypted_key.pem` is the unencrypted private key.)

NOTE: Make sure you delete any trailing spaces or line feeds!

That should do it.

## Debugging:

If, when you paste the certs into the GAE Settings page, you get an `invalid` error:

- Make sure you delete any trailing line feeds or spaces!
- If it still won't accept your PEM files, replace the code from `unencrypted_key.pem` with the code from the original `privkey.pem`

If you get homebrew error:

```
$ cd /usr/local/Library
$ sudo git pull origin master
```

if get augeas error:

```
$ brew install augeas
```

if get Warning: augeas-1.4.0 already installed, it's just not linked

```
$ sudo brew link augeas
```

if ExecutableNotFound:

```
$ brew install dialog
```

if get Warning: dialog-1.2-20150920 already installed, it's just not linked

```
$ sudo brew link dialog
```

## Renewing:

```
$ cd certbot
$ ./certbot-auto certonly --debug --force-renew -a manual -d www.yoursite.com -d yoursite.com
```

( You may get an "unable to reach..." error, but the certs still created.)
Change directory to where pem files are placed:

```
$ cd /private/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yoursite.com
```

Create unencrypted key (this is the one you upload to GAE.  If fails, use the original privkey.pem):

```
$ sudo openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out unencrypted_key.pem
```

`fullchain.pem` is the public key.
`unencrypted_key.pem` is the unencrypted private key

Go to GAE Settings and install as outlined above.